# poll() and commitAsync() in Spring-Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to write a kafka consumer application in java on
Springboot platform. Earlier, I have written code in plain java but
now converting into spring-kafka as it can give some advantage over
plain java. I do have few questions that I am trying to understand.

- It seems that I don't have to explicitly poll() loop in spring-kafka
  and it would be handled automatically by @KafkaListener?
- I have set enable.auto.commit='false', As I have to do some
  processing before committing offsets, how can I perform commitAsync() in
  Spring-Kafka?

  **ConsumerConfig.java :**

  ```
  @EnableKafka
  @Configuration
  public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

      @Value("${app.kafka_brokers}")
      private String KAFKA_BROKERS;

      @Value("${app.topic}")
      private String KAFKA_TOPIC;

      @Value("${app.group_id_config}")
      private String GROUP_ID_CONFIG;

      @Value("${app.schema_registry_url}")
      private String SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL;

      @Value("${app.offset_reset}")
      private String OFFSET_RESET;

      @Value("${app.max_poll_records}")
      private String MAX_POLL_RECORDS;

      @Value("${app.security.protocol}")
      private String SSL_PROTOCOL;

      @Value("${app.ssl.truststore.password}")
      private String SSL_TRUSTSTORE_SECURE;

      @Value("${app.ssl.keystore.password}")
      private String SSL_KEYSTORE_SECURE;

      @Value("${app.ssl.key.password}")
      private String SSL_KEY_SECURE;

      @Value("${app.ssl.truststore.location}")
      private String SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_FILE_NAME;

      @Value("${app.ssl.keystore.location}")
      private String SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_FILE_NAME;

      @Bean
      public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory(){

          Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,KAFKA_BROKERS);
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, OFFSET_RESET);
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, GROUP_ID_CONFIG);
          props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");

          props.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, SSL_PROTOCOL);
          props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_FILE_NAME);
          props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, SSL_TRUSTSTORE_SECURE);
          props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG,SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_FILE_NAME);
          props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, SSL_KEYSTORE_SECURE);
          props.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEY_PASSWORD_CONFIG, SSL_KEY_SECURE);

          return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);

      }

      @Bean
      ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> 
      kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                              new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        return factory;
    }

  }
  ```

**KafkaConsumer.java :**

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {
    
    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic", groupId = "group")
    public void run(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record) {
        
        System.out.println(record);
        
    <-- how to asyncCommit()--> 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I suggest you use the properties and AutoConfiguration set by Spring kafka instead of creating your own as it follows the **DRY Principle**: Don't Repeat Yourself.

```
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: ${app.kafka_brokers}
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: ${app.offset_reset}
      enable-auto-commit: false   // <---- disable auto committing
    ssl:
      protocol: ${app.security.protocol}
      key-store-location: ${app.ssl.keystore.location}
      key-store-password:  ${app.ssl.keystore.password}
      trust-store-location: ${app.ssl.truststore.location}
      trust-store-password: ${app.ssl.truststore.password}
  // And other properties
    listener:
      ack-mode: manual // This is what you need
```

The `AckMode` docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerProperties.AckMode.html

Essentially, `manual` is an asynchronous acknowledgment, while `manual_immediate` is synchronous.

Then inside your `@KafkaListener` component you can inject `org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment` object acknowledge your message.

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {
    
    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic", groupId = "group")
    public void run(ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        
        System.out.println(record);
        
        acknowledgment.acknowledge();
    }

}
```

Here's the documentation for what can be injected into a `@KafkaListener` method: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#message-listeners

Answer (score 1):

The listener container will commit the offset when the listener exits normally, depending on the container's `AckMode` property; `AckMode.BATCH` (default) means the offsets for all the records returned by the poll will be committed after they have all been processed, `AckMode.RECORD` means each offset will be committed as soon as the listener exits.

`sync` Vs. `async` is controlled by the `syncCommits` container property.